# JWT (JSON Web Tokens) in a webhook for Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es, webhooks

How can I implement JWT (JSON Web Tokens) authentication for my webhook in Dialogflow, ensuring secure communication between my chatbot and external services?

I have tried OAuth and API keys but I would like to use JWT specifically.